# How to test CompletableFuture class's handle() method with Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, amazon-ses, completable-future

I have the following code with me:

```
SendEmailRequest request = getEmailMeta(toEmail, fromEmail, subject, htmlBody);
return sesAsyncClient.sendEmail(request)
    .handle((res, exp) -> {
        if (exp != null || res.messageId()==null || res.messageId().isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}catch (Exception e){
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(false);
}
```

`getEmailMeta()` is a helper function which returns a `SendEmailRequest` object, and works fine.

`sesAsyncClient.sendEmail(request)` of type `SESAsyncClient` returns `CompletableFuture<SendEmailResponse>` object which is then fed into the [handle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#handle-java.util.function.BiFunction-) function. Now I'm trying to mock `sesAsyncClient` object so that I can test its functionality without actually calling the service.

I have written the following mockito statement

```
Mockito.when(sesAsyncClient.sendEmail(any(SendEmailRequest.class)))
.thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(SendEmailResponse.builder().messageId(null).build()));
```

The problem is, the control flow never enters the `handle` function and just directly goes to the `catch` statement. Any help on how can I evaluate the bifunction in handle?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Suppose I pass the `fromEmail` field in `getEmailMeta` as `""` (empty string). There won't be any error in the first line, i.e, constructing the `SendEmailRequest` object. But, when the `request` is input to `sendEmail` in the next line, and *without using handle()*, I get the an error `SESAsyncClient: CompletionException: "From" field cannot remain empty` and then the `catch` statement catches this very exception. But if `handle()` is there, then I'm unable to see green lines in the coverage tools on all the lines inside the `handle()` method, except the input args. See the attached screenshot.

[image: No coverage on lambda function]

Comment: Are you sure that your `sesAsyncClient` is properly injected into your service? Also, if it enters the `catch` block, it means something else went wrong (maybe an NPE?). You should provide a [mcve] because the provided code is not sufficient to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Your edit confuses me a bit more now, you were first talking about mocking the `sesAsyncClient`, and now you mention an issue with the actual implementation. Also, adding `handle()`shouldn't change anything if `sendEmail()` already throws an exception. It would only affect things if `sendEmail()`actually returns `null`. An [mcve] would be really important to understand all of this, with the corresponding inputs/outputs.